# Making scrollable div in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am making React project but I faced error with css.
Is there any possible way to leave parent and child component same and just make scroll on the left side for the div where are shopping items. I tried with **overwflow-y: scroll** but it just creates scroll and doesn't make scrollable even if I put some random height. There is way I know but unfortunately at the moment I cant find it.

[image]

Parent html

```js
const CartModal = () => {
  const { totalPrice, totalAmount } = useSelector((state) => state.cart);

  return (
    <div className={classes["cart-modal"]}>
      <div className={classes["cart-modal__navbar"]}></div>
      <div className={classes["cart-modal__body"]}>
        <div className={classes["body__left-side"]}>
          <h1>ORDERS</h1>
          <CartModalFoodList />
        </div>
        <div className={classes["body__right-side"]}>
          <div>
            <img src={BigCart} />
          </div>
          <div>
            <h2>Total price:</h2>
            <h2>{totalPrice}$</h2>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h2>Total amount:</h2>
            <h2>{totalAmount}</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
.cart-modal {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 65vw;
  height: 75vh;
  background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cart-modal__navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15vh;
  background: radial-gradient(
    50% 50% at 50% 50%,
    var(--gradient-color-one) 0%,
    var(--gradient-color-two) 100%
  );
}

.cart-modal__body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.body__left-side {
  height: 100%;
  width: 55%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0 3.5%;
}

.body__left-side h1 {
  color: var(--strong-yellow);
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--weak-yellow);
  padding-bottom: 2%;
}

.body__right-side {
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.body__right-side div:first-child {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}

.body__right-side div:first-child img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.body__right-side *:not(:first-child) {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.body__right-side *:not(:first-child) h2 {
  font-size: 2vw;
  margin: 2.5% 0;
}
```

Left side div

```
const MenuList = (props) => {
  const page = props.page;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const foodArray = props.foodList;

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();
  const params = useParams();

  const [foodList, setFoodList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFoodList(formatArray(foodArray));
  }, [foodArray]);

  const queryPrams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  const sort = queryPrams.get("sort");

  const onNextPageHandler = () => {
    dispatch(uiSliceActions.updatePage("forward"));
  };
  const onPreviousPageHandler = () => {
    dispatch(uiSliceActions.updatePage("backward"));
  };
  const onSortPageHandler = () => {
    navigate(
      `/menu/${params.foodId ? params.foodId + "/" : ""}?sort=${
        sort === "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
      }`
    );
    let foodListPart = foodList[page];
    let foodListSort = foodList;

    const sortFoodList = (sort) => {
      foodListPart = foodListPart.sort((a, b) =>
        sort === "asc" ? a.foodPrice - b.foodPrice : b.foodPrice - a.foodPrice
      );
      foodListSort[page] = foodListPart;
      setFoodList(foodListSort);
    };
    sort === "asc" ? sortFoodList("asc") : sortFoodList("desc");
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className={classes["menu-list"]}>
        {foodList[page]
          ? foodList[page].map((foodObj) => (
              <MenuItem key={foodObj.id} foodObj={foodObj} />
            ))
          : ""}
      </div>
      <div className={classes["menu-list__buttons"]}>
        {page >= 1 && (
          <Button type="button" onClick={onPreviousPageHandler}>
            Page {page}
          </Button>
        )}
        <Button
          type="button"
          onClick={onSortPageHandler}
          className={classes["sort-button"]}
        >
          {sort === "asc" ? `Descending` : `Ascending`}
        </Button>
        <Button type="button" onClick={onNextPageHandler}>
          Page {page + 2}
        </Button>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

And css for that div

```css
.menu-list {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: **.menu-list {** should have a height. However, you haven't provided the generated code so that we can actually create a working example. [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Define the height of the div, then add `overflow: auto;`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add overflow-y: scroll to "body__left-side" class

```
 .body__left-side {
   height: 100%;
   width: 55%;
   background-color: white;
   padding: 0 3.5%;
   overflow-y: scroll;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

just add `over-flow: "auto"` to  **cart-modal__body** class

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by correcting **.body__left-side**

```css
.body__left-side {
  height: 100%;
  width: 55%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0 3.5%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

And also by correcting **.menu-list**

```css
.menu-list {
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
}
```

Thanks to everyone for help.